Apply Bootstrap custom validation only to invalid fields
I am learning about Bootstrap, and I was wondering if there is a simple way of changing the style of a field only when it is invalid?


<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
  <form class="needs-validation was-validated" novalidate>
    <label for="sample" class="form-label">Number</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="sample" min="1" step="1" required />
  </form>
</div>



This is the code I am playing around with. I can get the input field green/red for valid/invalid. I only want it to be red when it is invalid, and remain gray (and not have the green check mark) when it is valid.

It's not really clear what you're asking. Do you want the field to be red all the time, no matter what value is in it?

@Phil No, I want it to be red only when it is invalid. I want it to look the same way it looks without the was-validated when it is valid. Does that make more sense?

By targeting the correct classes in CSS you can revert the changes from bootstrap :
.container .form-control.is-valid, .container .was-validated .form-control:valid {
    border-color: initial;
    background-image: none;
    padding-inline-end: 12px;
}

.container .form-control.is-valid:focus, .container .was-validated .form-control:valid:focus {
   border-color: initial;
   box-shadow: initial;
}

With this, only the red/invalid will remain.
Demo:


.container .form-control.is-valid, .container .was-validated .form-control:valid {
    border-color: initial;
    background-image: none;
    padding-inline-end: 12px;
}

.container .form-control.is-valid:focus, .container .was-validated .form-control:valid:focus {
   border-color: initial;
   box-shadow: initial;
}
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
  <form class="needs-validation was-validated" novalidate>
    <label for="sample" class="form-label">Number</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="sample" min="1" step="1" required />
  </form>
</div>




When it is gray/valid, it still has the gap to the right of the arrows where the check mark was. This gap is not there without the was-validated. Is there a way to get rid of this as well?

This is exactly what I wanted. Thanks. Just a follow-up question: Is there an easy way for me to find out what are the changes from bootstrap that I want to revert? For example I now want to do this for some check boxes as well. I understand that I should change the form-control to form-check-input, but how to find out the rest?

You can use the Developer Tools in your browser (F12 in chrome). Click on the inspector icon then click on an element you want to inspect on your page. The associated css will be displayed. From there you can enabled/disable css properties and check from which file this css property is coming from.
